# Does it drain my Sony a7 battery to have "remote trigger" activated?

Tags: sony, battery, wireless-triggers, sony-alpha, battery-drain

Deep in the menus of my Sony a7 there is a menu item to allow remote trigger. If I don't put this in the "ON" position, remote triggers won't work.

I don't use remote triggers often, just for landscapes. If I leave this feature on all the time, will it cause extra drain on my battery?

Answer (score 1):

It will, because it enables the internal radio receiver for the trigger. How much it will drain depends on many factors, mostly on how much you're actually using the remote trigger itself.

If you are not using it (the remote trigger) most of the time, the drain should be minimal, because the receiver it will enter a standby mode to save energy - although it will still be on and using energy.